# Splitting field of a finite field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field

Let , $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$ is splitting field extension of the separable polynomial $x^{p^{n}}-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. What should look like the extension with the generators and what will be the degree of extension?

I didn't understand how should I go ahead. First, the given polynomial is not irreducible.

What if I go for irreducible factor and then is it a cyclotomic polynomial always?

Euler function doesn't help much for finding the degree of that cyclotomic polynomial.

So, I got stuck totally.

What should I do?

Comment: The degree is simply $[\Bbb F_{p^n}:\Bbb F_p]=n$. There are several useful posts here on this topic, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219213/a-question-on-the-irreducible-divisors-and-splitting-field-of-xpn-x-in-m?rq=1) and so on.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$ is just taken as namely,,, but main problem is the given polynomial,, can you say from that the degree is actually $n$?

Comment: Yes, you can, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1464191/prove-l-mathbbf-p-n?rq=1).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde how do you know there is irreducible factor of degree $n$?

Comment: By [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219213/a-question-on-the-irreducible-divisors-and-splitting-field-of-xpn-x-in-m?rq=1)?